# Is this function lower semicontinuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Prove or disprove that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x, y) =\begin{cases} 
x^2+y^2-1 & \text{ if } (x,y) \in\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\leq 1\} \\
x^2+y^2 & \text{ if } (x,y) \in\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}> 1\} \end{cases} $$ is lower semicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think it it lower semicontinuous. $f$ is discontinuous in $z_0=||z||_{\mathbb{R}^2} =1$ and I need to show that $$lim inf_{z\to z_0}f(z)\geq f(z). $$

I don't know how to work with multidimensional $f$... what is lim inf?

I tried: for $||z||_{\mathbb{R}^2} =\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\leq 1$ it is $f(z)\leq 1-1=0$ and for $||z||>1$ it is $f(z)>1$ with $z=(z_1,z_2)$.

So $0=f(z)\leq lim_{z\uparrow z_0}f(z)\leq0<1<lim_{z\downarrow z_0}f(z)$. Is $lim_{z\uparrow z_0}f(z)=lim inf_{z\to z_0}f(z)$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions you only have to consider sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ when dealing
with $\lim\,,$ $\limsup\,,$ and/or $\liminf$ of $f(x,y)\,.$

The simplest way to show lower semicontinuity for your function is however this:

- Take the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) that $f$ is l.s.c. when for each $c$ the set $\{c<f\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^2\,.$
- When $f$ is continuous in $(x,y)$ and $c<f(x,y)$ then it is trivial that there is an open neighborhood $U$ such that $(x,y)\in U\subset\{c<f\}\,.$
- Therefore we only have to consider points with $x^2+y^2=1$ at which $f$ is discontinuous. Since $f\le 1$ inside the unit disc it follows that every $c$ with $c<f(x,y)$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ must be strictly less than one: $c<1\,.$
- The function $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ is continuous and agrees with $f$ in the unit disc and on its boundary. Therefore, when $x^2+y^2=1$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ such that
  $(x,y)\in U\subset\{c<g\}\,.$ Since $f\ge 1$ outside the unit disc and since $c<1$ it follows that $c<f(z_1,z_2)$ for all $(z_1,z_2)\in U\,.$ Therefore,
  $$
  (x,y)\in U\subset\{c<f\}\,.
  $$

Here is a proof that uses $\liminf$:

- Since $f\ge -1$ the $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)$ exists for every
  sequence $z_n\,.$
- When $z_0$ is on the boundary and the sequence $z_n$ converges from outside to $z_0$ then clearly $\liminf f(z_n)=\lim f(z_n)=1\,.$
- When $z_n$ converges from inside to $z_0$ (on the boundary) then $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} f(z_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(z_n)=f(z_0)$ and $f(z_0)=0\,.$
- Now consider a general sequence $z_n$ that converges to $z_0$
  on the boundary. Any subsequence for which $f(z_n)$ converges has itself a subsequence $z_{n_i}$ that converges either from inside or from outside to $z_0\,.$ Therefore, in both cases $f(z_{n_i})$ converges to a value that is at least $f(z_0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But our definition is: $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ is lower semicontinuous in $z_0$ if $lim inf_{z\to z_0}f(z) \geq f(z_0)$. That's why I did the ansatz above but I'm struggling to find lim inf

Comment: Ah so you mean if $z_n\downarrow z_0$ (from the outside with $z_n=(x_n,y_n) $) then lim inf $f(z_n)=$lim$f(z_n)=1$ and if $z_n\uparrow z_0$(from the inside) then lim inf $f(z_n)=$ lim $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$ and $f(z_0)=0\leq 1$ as wished in the definition. So both cases show the wished result and for any sequence, $f(z_n)\to f(z)\geq f(z_0)$. But does lim inf $f(z_n)$ exist in both cases?

Comment: 1. $f(z_0)$ is not zero but always less or equal to $1$ for $z_0$ on the boundary. 2. the liminf is the smallest accumulation point of a sequence. the only case when this does not exist is when the sequence diverges to $-\infty$. For your function this cannot happen because it is bounded from below by $-1$ ( will add this to the answer ).

Comment: One last question: we need to discuss the points with $x^2+y^2=1$ since $f$ is discontinuous thrre. Is $z_0=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$ the critical point or what is $z_0$? If so, isn't $f(z_0)=0$ then?

Comment: Why is $lim_{z_n\to z_0}=1$ from the outside then? I thought because $f(z)=x^2+y^2$ then. So $lim_{z_n\to z_0}=f(z_0)=1-1=0$ from the inside for $z_0=(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2=1$ since this is the point on which $f$ is discontinuous...

Comment: Your last sentence: "converges to a value that is at least $f(z_0)$", shouldn't it be "at most" since we need (and you showed it) lim inf$z\to z_0f(z)\geq f(z_0)?$

Comment: Correct when $z_0$ has $x^2+y^2=1$ then $f(z_0)=0$. You will probably remember a version of your question where in the unit ball $f(x,y)$ was $x^2\color{red}{-}y^2-1$. This may have caused a bit of confusion. The limit of $x^2+y^2$ from the outside when $(x,y)$ converge to the boundary is clearly $1$. What else should it be ? I don't know how this could be explained in other words. Regarding your last comment: ***No***. We converge to $1$ or $0$ which is ***at least*** $0$.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I did a typo in my first version! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You may want to prove the lower semi continuity now for the function in that first version. Good exercise.

Comment: Yes you are right, at least is correct, sorry